# Mercurial backslash forward slash issue

Tags: mercurial, backslash

We have a sub-repository in mercurial that was created using hg convert.  For about three weeks we've had people modifying and checking in changes (using Tortoise under Windows) before we noticed that we have two versions of the originally converted files:

e.g.

```
Dir\Project/FileName.ext
Dir/Project/FileName.ext
```

I've tried `hg rename`, `hg forget`, `hg remove`, but when we always seem to end up with both files gone, or both files present.  I've also looked at the case folding suggestions, but they don't appear to apply.

Any suggestions on fixing would be appreciated.  If we lose the history on the \ version that would not be the end of the world.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean both files appear on the disk?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen with converted SVN repositories (using [hgsubversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion) but I bet [`hg convert`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) has the same issue). In the cases I've seen it there was an svn properties change for the path which apparently resulted in a "filename containing backslashes" (*not* path) being stored in svn.

In the first case I saw it was a directory path which caused me to immediately encounter the problem - a zero-length file was created with the directory path on Windows, and then later in the update Mercurial aborted because it was unable to create the directory of the same name.

I expect the sequence that created the double entries is something like:

1. Update to revision which contains filepath with backslashes
2. The new file shows as untracked because the Mercurial manifest currently contains a path with backslashes, but when looking at the working dir it normalises all file paths to forward slashes - so it doesn't appear in the manifest.
3. User adds the "new" file.
4. On subsequent updates, both paths are updated but one overwrites the other in the working directory. If you've been lucky the new version is the one that's ended up in the working dir.

You probably can't fix this on Windows but you should be able to remove the backslash versions on Linux (or other UNIX-like OS with case-sensitive filesystem) by single-quoting the filename e.g. `hg rm 'Dir\Project\FileName.ext'`. If you update to a revision with the problem on Linux you should see files actually named `'Dir\Project\FileName.ext'` in the root of the working directory.

Just make sure that the backslash version is the one that should be removed - if not you may need to manually merge them together to get the result you want.